# php how to sort data by key in different array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array $data

```
[0] => Array
    {
        [configuration_id] => 5542abf530830
        [primary_language] => fr_MA       
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abf4c0721
        [primary_language] => en_IL
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abf3ec1f4
        [primary_language] => en_IL
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abf38933a
        [primary_language] => en_AE     
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abf2b5069 
        [primary_language] => uk_UA
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abf1df2c8
        [primary_language] => tr_TR
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abf114768
        [primary_language] => ru_RU
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abf03f401
        [primary_language] => pl_PL

    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abef6be61
        [primary_language] => hu_HU
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abef080cb
        [primary_language] => hu_HU
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abee980a8
        [primary_language] => cs_CZ
    )


[12] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abedc5422
        [primary_language] => zh_TW
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abed60bad
        [primary_language] => zh_TW
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abecf12ac
        [primary_language] => zh_CN
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abec28ff1            
        [primary_language] => ko_KR
    }

[16] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abeb54eaf
        [primary_language] => sv_SE
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abe529770     
        [primary_language] => da_DK
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abe407af9
        [primary_language] => fr_FR
   }

[19] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abea828f7
        [primary_language] => pt_BR
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [configuration_id] => 5542abdc37fb9
        [primary_language] => en_US
    )
```

Also, other array to each language belongs to which tier group as follows,

```
$tier0_languages = array("en_US");
$tier1_languages = array("ja_JP", "de_DE", "fr_FR");
$tier2_languages = array("it_IT","es_ES","es_MX","nl_NL","pt_BR","da_DK","fi_FI","nb_NO","sv_SE");
$tier3_languages = array("ko_KR","zh_CN","zh_TW");
$tier4_languages = array("cs_CZ","ru_RU","tr_TR","pl_PL","hu_HU","uk_UA","fr_MA","en_AE","en_IL");
```

I would like to sort $data by each language group. $tier0_language first, $tier1_language next and so on. How can I write php code to do that? Please advise.

Comment: the only approach i can see is looping the tiers and then looping the data to get the items that are in the tires - not highly efficient - can you sort the data closer to the source?

Comment: uksort(); perhaps?  I would make the languages into a simple set of regular expressions and then test them in uksort on the key

Comment: The best way to do is merge all your `$tier` arrays and then use `uasort()`

Answer (score 0):

I would first compile the language arrays into a set of regular expressions such as this

```
$expr1 = '('.implode('|', $tier0_languages).')';
```

So in the end you have something like this

```
(en_US)|(ja_JP|de_DE|fr_FR)...
```

but with all of the languages in order, then it is relatively trivial to do preg_match, and uksort, using the match index as the order ( using PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE ).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply merge your `$tier(int)_languages` and sort it using `uasort` as

```
$tier0_languages = array("en_US");
$tier1_languages = array("ja_JP", "de_DE", "fr_FR");
$tier2_languages = array("it_IT","es_ES","es_MX","nl_NL","pt_BR","da_DK","fi_FI","nb_NO","sv_SE");
$tier3_languages = array("ko_KR","zh_CN","zh_TW");
$tier4_languages = array("cs_CZ","ru_RU","tr_TR","pl_PL","hu_HU","uk_UA","fr_MA","en_AE","en_IL");

$tier = array_merge($tier0_languages,$tier1_languages,$tier2_languages,$tier3_languages,$tier4_languages);

uasort($arr, function ($a,$b) use ($tier){
    foreach($tier as $value){
        if($value == $a['primary_language']){
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        if($value == $b['primary_language']){
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
});

print_r($arr);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://eval.in/404593)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I want. It works great.

Comment: _(FYI : You can accept or upvote an answer which really helps you...)_